# Aurelia observable with object property

Tags: aurelia, observable

I'm trying to set a watch on when an object property changes in Aurelia.  I haven't used observables before so please help me.  Based on the documentation, here's what I think would work, but I suspect the dot is throwing off the function name or observable.

```
export class EventEdit {
  record = {
    ev_date_start,
    ev_date_end,
    ev_description
  };
  @observable record.ev_date_start;

  record.ev_date_startChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("ev_date_start changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
  }
}
```

Nothing happens when I change the value of ev_date_start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's better to define a class when you need a complex object.

```
import { observable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class EventEdit {
  constructor() {
    this.model = new EventModel();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.model.ev_date_start = "test";
    }, 2000);
  }
}

export class EventModel  {
    @observable ev_date_start;
    ev_date_end;
    ev_description;

    ev_date_startChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log("ev_date_start changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    }
}
```

Another solution is using the BindingEngine:

```
import {inject, BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class EventEdit {
  record = {
    ev_date_start,
    ev_date_end,
    ev_description
  };

  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }

  attached() {
    this.subs = this.bindingEngine
       .propertyObserver(this.record, 'ev_date_start')
       .subscribe(this.ev_date_startChanged);
  }

  detached() {
    this.subs.dispose();
  }

  ev_date_startChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("ev_date_start changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping to avoid that since there are a lot of properties I didn't include to keep the example simple.  I'll watch to see if there are any other solutions for the next day or two and if there are none, I'll mark yours as the accepted answer.  Thanks for taking the time, Fabio!

Comment: There's another solution I'll post it

Comment: See the updated answer! I'll see if there's a way using @observable

Comment: Fabio, I'm finding that inside my `ev_date_startChanged(newValue, oldValue)` function, I don't have access to my viewmodel or record.  If I do `console.log(this.record.ev_date_end);` I get undefined.  `this` is not available to me.  Do you know why?

Comment: Okay, I found that if I change `.subscribe(this.ev_date_startChanged);` to `.subscribe(() => this.ev_date_startChanged());`, it works.

Comment: _Filling in more info on the above for others coming here later:_ ...because lambdas, e.g. `x => ...`, capture `this` from where the lambda was created, whereas a directly passed function has no capture of `this` (meaning `this` will either be undefined -or- could sometimes be set by the code that calls the function you passed in. For example browser event handling often sets `this` to the element that caused the event, and a different example is Array.map, which lets you explicitly pass in what this should be when it calls your function, e.g. `myArray.map(this.mySelectFunction, this)`.